# Need explanation of syntaxis of Qt 5.0 method native event

Tags: c++, winapi, qt5

**I am trying to send a system message from parent process to a child process.**
1. I registered message within parent method:

```
UINT msg = RegisterWindowMessageA("my message");
```

2.In the child application I override method nativeEvent.
I found syntax of that method in Qt assistant, but info provided not enough, because argument usage not described there.

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message,
        long* result)
{
    UINT mssg = RegisterWindowMessage(L"my message");
    UINT recivedMssg = *static_cast<UINT*>(message);
    if (recivedMssg == mssg)
    {
        *result = 0;
        QMessageBox::information(this,"",QString::number(recivedMssg));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I did this implementation, but it doesn`t work as I expect, I considered that void* message - is number of message.
So **my question is:** how in nativeEvent I can get message which was sent from the parent process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't play with Qt5 yet but I doubt that there is any difference.
For Windows you should cast message as follows:

```
MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
```

Where MSG is Windows specific structure declared in some Windows header(windows.h will be enough for sure)

Comment: I did `MSG* mssg = RegisterWindowMessage(L"my message");
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if (msg == mssg)` but didn't get it to work because of erroneous cast. How come? Thanks